# how to highlight the text in android, when user long press on text

Tags: android

I am a newbie in android. I want to implement highlight feature in my app such that when the user long press any text then the text is highlighted ,as in other pdf readers like repligo etc.

Please suggest me...

Comment: How much text to highlight?  The current letter?  Word? Sentence?  Paragraph?  All of it?

Comment: I want to highlight the current word.